# "Implicit representations" of algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a system of polynomial equations $S$ in multiple variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$.

Is there a simple characterization of when the following property holds:

There exists a set of polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_n$ in variables $y_1,\dots,y_m$ such that:

1) For all assignments of $y_1,\dots,y_m$, the assignment $x_1=f_1,\dots,x_n=f_n$ satisfies $S$
2) For all satisfying assignments of $S$ there exists an assignment to $y_1,\dots,y_m$ such that $f_1=x_1,\dots,f_n=x_n$

I'd particularly like to know if this property has a name or has been studied at all, and especially if there's a method to find such a set if one exists!

A very simple example of this is to consider the determinant of a rank one 2 by 2 matrix: $m_{1,1}\cdot m_{2,2}-m_{1,2}\cdot m_{2,1}=0$. By considering the SVD of such a matrix we can get the following:
$m_{1,1}=y_1\cdot y_3$
$m_{1,2}=y_2\cdot y_3$
$m_{2,1}=y_1\cdot y_4$
$m_{2,2}=y_2\cdot y_4$
for which the property above clearly holds.

I have very little formal instruction in algebraic geometry or related fields, so it's possible I'm lacking some basic concepts to recognize this! Apologies if the title doesn't clearly represent what I'm asking.

Comment: (I hope I'm understanding your question correctly.) Algebraic varieties like this, that can be parametrised by polynomial functions, are called _unirational_ varieties. (Actually that notion is a bit more general, but it includes what you want.) They have been studied a great deal! A Google search for _unirational vareity_ should get you started, although the results might be difficult to digest if you don't have an algebraic geometry background.

Comment: If you have a more specific question, you could ask that here, and it might be possible to tackle that in a more down-to-earth way.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! They do seem quite difficult to digest, but I'll give it a try. Could you possibly explain in simple terms how they generalize this idea? I'd still particularly like to know if I can find such representations for small examples, when they exist.

Comment: Dear user159469, if I have time later I'll try to expand on my comments a bit.

Comment: Thanks once again, @AsalBeagDubh. I'll see what I can figure out from Google in the mean time!

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Later, always later :). Just a reminder in case you forgot about this thread.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh I'm still struggling with this; if you have an opportunity to write anything further it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dear user159649, I'm afraid I don't have anything concrete to say about your problem at the moment.